# 3 phase 4 wire inverter output common mode choke selection

Tags: power, power-electronics, inverter, common-mode, saturation

I designe and develope a stand alone 3 phase four wire inverter that it works with unbalanced output currents. The standard 3 phase 3 wire inverter output are used common mode choke like this (RB6132-36-0M4):

[image]
[image]
[image]

3 phase 3 wire inverter output is symmetrycal, therfore the 3 current will be symmetrycal.
But 3 phase four wire inverter can handle unbalanced output current. In this case, the same current does not flow through the common mode choke per phase.

I'm not sure, but won't this lead to saturation of the choke if the phases of the 3-phase choke are not the same current?

And if it true, I need to use single inductors, not common mode choke?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Why would you not use a 4-wire CMC?

Comment: I think I will use 4 wire common mode choke, but this type is not very common and I thought it could be solved with the more common 3-wire choke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I'm not sure, but won't this lead to saturation of the choke if the
> phases of the 3-phase choke are not the same current?*

It should be of significant concern but, whether a level of saturation is reached that causes problems is impossible to say.

> *And if it true, I need to use single inductors, not common mode choke?*

No, if the imbalance is not 100% then using a common core is still likely to be both the cheapest solution and smallest solution.

Comment: Thank you Andy aka your answear! This inverter will be like a grid connected inverter with 230V rms Line_neutral voltage and 400V rms L-L voltage just stand alone. Therefore, the load can also be connected to Line-Neutral. If I understand correctly, in my case, I should not use this choke, because may be 100% imbalance?

Comment: It can be designed to work with 100% imbalance or, you can use individual inductors but, I can't tell you which is the best choice because there could be so many scenarios to analyse that it makes a definitive numerical answer impossible within the format of this site. I would encourage you to totally use a circuit simulation tool to solve this and see what core flux would peak at in the scenarios you may consider both now and those you haven't yet considered. Also please consider the comment from Tim Williams under your answer because it seems that could work very well.

Comment: Yes, I think the 4-wire CMC will be the solution, but not very common. However I need >=30A rated current capability.

Comment: Use a simulation tool is my advice. They are free and accurate.

Comment: Thank you Andy Aka your answers, I will simulate the choke and the circuit.